# How to deliver new features (Website)

Tags: html, web-deployment

I have recently been thinking about one of my websites. It's getting big and gaining a community and I have realized; how would I implement new features. Would I code instantly on the website or would I have to pull a backup and code on it then put it back up on the server. Because both methods seem to be inefficient.
Would there be a way that I can do such a thing, like a version system (similar to apps)?

Comment: Common sense says you don't develop using your production site. If you do something wrong and it's live code, you kill your site until it's fixed. Web development is no different than app development. You develop and test and debug on development code, not production code. There are entire books written about development methodology. This isn't a tutorial site, however.

Comment: So I would have to just code it on the localhost then? Or can I create a "development" folder on the server and just test it there?

Comment: No. You code it on your local machine, test it on the local machine, and only upload it to the server when it's ready. Again, they write **books** about this stuff. This isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: This site is for questions and all I did was ask one, I dislike the kind of people that come on here and just tell me not to ask a question?? I didn't force you to answer nor wasted your time.. it was a simple question to gain instant knowledge about this topic.

Comment: I'm not saying not to ask questions. But you can't ask us to teach you entire subjects or topics from scratch when there are **entire books written** about that topic. See the [help], in particular [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), which specifically says *if there are entire books written about a subject, then it's too broad to ask here*. And it's a very bad idea to get rude or snarky at a site where you depend on the kindness of people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a duplicate, test your code until you're satisfied. Check the edge cases. Try to break it. Then, when you're sure it's solid, roll it out to your users during very light usage because you might need to turn off  the whole site during the upgrade.

Testing, testing, testing is they key.

Comment: Duplicate on the server or localhost? And sure.. testing is key :)

Comment: Duplicate your production environment as closely as possible to avoid points of failure. Same configuration, same version of database, PHP (or whatever) same web server version, etc.

Comment: Ok, seems about right.. Thank you @Difster

Comment: Please mark the answer as Solved. Thanks!